# Using `includes` in Rails ActiveRecord by condition, without foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called Score, and a model called Adjustment. There is no association between them in the database, but they both have a field named `course`, and a field named `date`. An Adjustment belongs to a Score if they have the same `course` and the same `date`. So we can have multiple Adjustments belonging to the same Score.

I want to be able to get all Scores from the database along with their Adjustments, something along the lines of:

`scores = Score.all.includes(adjustments)`

So that, for each score, I should be able to do something like

`score.adjustments`

and get all adjustments that belong to that score.

I know I can do this using n+1 queries, but I'd like a more optimal solution.